# How to convert `geometry.faceVertexUvs` in `THREE.js` current version?

Tags: three.js

```js
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 64, 64, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 0, Math.PI);
const uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
const axis = 'x';
for (let i = 0; i < uvs.length; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
    uvs[i][j][axis] *= 0.5;
  }
}
```

geometry.faceVertexUvs is depreciated.
How to convert this reference to `THREE.js` current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new method uses `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry`. This stores each vertex attribute (position, normal, uv) in arrays, so you can fetch the UVs with [`BufferGeometry.getAttribute("uv");`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.getAttribute).

Once you've retreived the attribute, you'll end up with a [`BufferAttribute`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute), where you can access the `.array` property for each individual component:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 64, 64, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 0, Math.PI);

const uvAttribute = geometry.getAttribute("uv");
const uvArray = uvAttribute.array;

// Loop through all UVs
// UVs have 2 components, so we jump by 2 on each iteration
for (let i = 0; i < uvAttribute.length; i += 2) {
    uvArray[i + 0] = uvX;
    uvArray[i + 1] = uvY;
}

// Now we set the update flag to true so the GPU gets the new values
uvAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
```